# What is meant by "is driven by collisions between its atoms and molecules"?" in NASA's statement?

Tags: atmospheric-science, gas

"The behavior of a dense atmosphere is driven by collisions between its atoms and molecules." says https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/ladee-lunar-neon.

It seems to me that a gas's behavior depends on the number of particles, and their velocities, and that the collisions between the particles and the atoms of the surfaces the gas is in contact with are what cause the measurable features like pressure, mass, density and temperature. So what is meant by "is driven by collisions between its atoms and molecules"?

Comment: @JonCuster But you can't *measure* the pressure, mass, density, or temperature without a surface in contact with the gas, can you.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh - that is not correct at all. There are non-contact ways to measure most if not all of those parameters.

Comment: @JonCuster Isn't pressure defined as the average force per unit area of a surface? And likewise isn't temperature by the reading on a thermometer with it's surface in thermal equilibrium with the gas?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh - for pressure it does not have to be a true surface. One non-contact technique would be measuring the pressure broadening of an optical line. Similarly one can measure temperatures using rotational spectroscopy techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Mean free path of molecule is :
$$ \ell ={\frac {k_{\text{B}}T}{{\sqrt {2}} \sigma p}} = \overline {v} \cdot \tau $$
Where $\overline v$ is average molecule speed and $\tau$ collision time - average time duration molecule has until it's next collision.
So you see that gas state/temperature is dependent on molecule average speed **AND** collision time. Mean free path or collision time is also important in such gas processes like diffusion, convection, turbulence, etc. Probably this had NASA in mind.

Comment: Surely temperature depends only the average kinetic energy or momentum of each molecule?

Comment: Then explain, why mean free path can be expressed as $\ell =\overline {v} \cdot \tau$ ? Or do you think that it's just a stupid coincidence ?

Comment: It's not exactly a coincidence. Distance equals velocity times time.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh Then check my given formula, which shows relationship between temperature and collision time. And btw, you miss NASA point. Temperature is not everything. Other parameters matters too, like free path and collision time. They play crucial role in diffusion for example. Temperature alone can't explain diffusion. So it's correctly said that atmospheric processes (cyclones, winds, turbulence, etc) are defined by particle collisions in gas.